# Inserting columns to existing DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, ipython, dataframe

Very elementary question about a DataFrame.

I have the following:

```
import pandas as pd
dic = {'name':['joe strummer','johnny rotten'],'age':[73,80]}
df = pd.DataFrame(dic)

def pX(s):
    result=[]
    for i in s:
        x = pd.Series(i.split(' '))
        result.append(x)
    return result
df2 = pd.DataFrame(pX(df['name']))
df2.columns=['first','second']
df2
```

I would like df2 inserted into df, so that the columns in df are these - in this specific order:

first | second | name | age

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand your question right you'd like to concat df and df2, using the pandas concat will yield:

```
print pd.concat([df2,df], axis=1, join_axes=[df.index])

    first    second  age           name
0     joe  strummer   73   joe strummer
1  johnny    rotten   80  johnny rotten
```

One can also use pandas merge:

```
print pd.merge(df2,df,left_index=[df.index], right_index='True')

    first    second  age           name
0     joe  strummer   73   joe strummer
1  johnny    rotten   80  johnny rotten
```

Comment: Thanks Hugo, this works exactly as I require. I ended up using the DataFrame insert method but I think your idea of joining on the index column is better.

Comment: what would be the syntax if we wanted to achieve this using `merge`? Is it possible? Something like `pd.merge(df2,df,left_on=[df.index],right_on=[df2.index])` ... this errors.

Comment: @whytheq almost, if you rather want to use pandas merge you should not merge left_on and right_on since we want to merge on indices: `pd.merge(df2,df,left_index=[df.index], right_index='True')`

Comment: ok Hugo - so the index "column" isn't treated like a normal column which I would use `left_on` and `right_on` to join?

Comment: exactly, i'm not too familiar with the pandas merge though, rather have closer look [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html). You can also use `df2.join(df)`. I am however not sure when one should stick with `concat`, `merge` or `join` which would be interested to know..